# c++, multiple instances of a dll, singleton

Tags: c++, dll, singleton, multiple-instances

I have got a DLL in which a singleton is defined.

I have got an app which can load multiple instances of this DLL.

The DLL needs a singleton instance per DLL instance, otherwise it will crash.

I observed that there was only one singleton instance for multiple DLL instances. Why? How can I resolved it (if possible, without refactoring the singleton into something else)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a singleton, get what you pay for.

Comment: @Sanja: The question you linked is about dlls used in multiple applications having a single singleton. This question is about dlls used in a single application having multiple singletons.

Comment: @moala: Why (and how) do you think you are loading multiple instances of a DLL in a single app?

Comment: @interjay: insightfull, when adding trace infos in DllMain, I see that the DLL is only loaded once, and the instances of my plug-in are instanciated multiple times. Things are a little more clear now.

Comment: How exactly are you loading multiple instances of the same DLL in one process?

Comment: @Jörgen: In fact, I am not loading the DLL myself; as the dll is an app plug-in, the hosting apps are third-party apps. The loading part may differ from app to app, as I don't control it.

Comment: This question needs to be edited.  Loading a DLL more than once in *one* process isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you have multiple instances inside your **app**, which implies that they all live inside the same process.

Singletons like any other static member are limited to one per application regardless of whether they belong to an object loaded from a DLL etc.

Answer (score 1):

No way without refactoring your code. A DLL is "loaded" into the process space. Any static member defined in there is static for the process (a loaded DLL doesn't have its own memory).

You'll have to write a non-standard "singleton" to get multiple objects.

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't have the sources to the dll, then you must load it in different processes, one "singleton" per process. These could be simple child-processes to your main process that just handle the dll communication part.

Then of course, you must come with some communication scheme between your main process and your child processes, which will depend on how much you are using the dll. Is it just a couple of calls with a lot of data? Or a lot of different calls that differ from run to run?

Generally if you are using the dll to make more than a couple of simple calls it's probably easier to refactor your own code.

Comment: Well, good wrapping idea. May be a big or a small work depending on many parameters.